# Regex add paragraph to new line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can i convert this string

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pulvinar lorem lectus, vel aliquam est blandit accumsan. Maecenas nisi eros, ornare a euismod rutrum, rhoncus a massa.
>
> Hello world
>
> <b>Goodbye world</b>
>
> <h2>Some headings</h2>

to html like this in php with regex?

> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pulvinar lorem lectus, vel aliquam est blandit accumsan. Maecenas nisi eros, ornare a euismod rutrum, rhoncus a massa.</p>
>
> <p>Hello world</p>
>
> <p><b>Goodbye world</b></p>
>
> <h2>Some headings</h2>

### Solution

You can find solution [here](https://3v4l.org/rks54). All answers were useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `preg_replace` with `multiline` flag can achieve this.

See [this](https://3v4l.org/nqZSl):

```
$str = <<<"MIXED"
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pulvinar lorem    lectus, vel aliquam est blandit accumsan. Maecenas nisi eros, ornare a euismod    rutrum, rhoncus a massa.
Hello world
<b>Goodbye world</b>
MIXED;

$str = preg_replace('/^(.*)$/m',"<p>$1</p>",$str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most likeley fastest way, is to not use a regex ;-)

```
$string= <<<STRING
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus pulvinar
lorem lectus, vel aliquam est blandit accumsan. Maecenas nisi eros, ornare a       
uismod rutrum, rhoncus a massa.

Hello world

<b>Goodbye world</b>
STRING;
echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', explode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $string)) . '</p>';
```

Comment: I have to admit, I forgot one PHP_EOL in my first shot.